# modify query to get percentages of values relative to column value

Tags: mysql

How can I modify my query so it selects all of a particular value in field1 and gets the percentages of the prices for that value in field1?

```
select round((count(*)*100)/(select count(*) from test),1) as percent from test group by field1 order by percent desc
```

Example MySQL table with data:

```
+--------+-------+---------------+
| field1 | price | ip            |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 122    | 50    | 192.168.0.120 |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 122    | 37    | 97.143.5.100  |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 122    | 50    | 64.234.1.060  |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 145    | 40    | 12.432.0.100  |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 145    | 20    | 20.359.2.200  |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 145    | 120   | 21.400.1.354  |
+--------+-------+---------------+
```

What I need for each query:

For 122:

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| field1 | price | Percentage |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 122    | 50    | 66.6%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 122    | 37    | 33.3%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

For 145:

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| field1 | price | Percentage |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 145    | 40    | 33.3%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 145    | 20    | 33.3%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 145    | 120   | 33.3%      |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT
    t.field1,
    t.price,
    concat(
        cast(
            CAST(
                (
                    count(*) * 1.0 / subQuery_t.totlaField1Count
                ) * 100 AS DECIMAL (18, 1)
            ) AS CHAR
        ),
        '%'
    ) AS Percentage
FROM
    test AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        innerT.field1,
        count(innerT.field1) AS totlaField1Count
    FROM
        test AS innerT
    GROUP BY
        innerT.field1
) AS subQuery_t ON t.field1 = subQuery_t.field1
GROUP BY
    t.field1,
    t.price
ORDER BY
    t.field1,
    t.price DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the subquery to the outer query so that the count applies to the specific `field1`:

```
select 
    field1, price, 
    concat(format(count(price) /( (select count(*) from test where field1 = t.field1) * 1.0),4)*100,'%')
    as "Percentage"
from test t 
group by field1, price;
```

This would produce a result like:

```
field1  price   Percentage
122     37      33.33%
122     50      66.67%
145     20      33.33%
145     40      33.33%
145     120     33.33%
```